# Canvas vs DOM Element game and collision

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, game-physics

So I am trying to make a little game both for practice and fun (first time I have tried) never had anything to do with it before..

You can see what I've tried so far at: http://myfirstgame.e-ddl.com/ been working on it for like 6-8 hours or so. So far and realized I would better ask before going on.

The way I have it now, I have a main loop that runs every 20 milliseconds or so. Ihis loop calls 2 functions:

1. Handle keystrokes (which iterates through the obstacles array and check if the player's future position collide any obstacle object and change the players' properties to the future position values).
2. It goes through the "need update" array and change the element's CSS details to reflect the changes made.

I have several questions:

- Is the above a good idea to handle collision? if not what would be a better way (I mean at around 800-1500 obstacle objects on map the game slows down).
- To calculate distance, I use distance between 2 points equation. If I only have 1 point, angle and distance. How can I find the 2nd point's (x, y)?
- What would be better, canvas or DOM ? (not important question as I already have it done with DOM).

Comment: The only valid answer to a question which includes the words "what is better" is "it depends".

Comment: Yea thats part of the whole question which isnt that important to me as i have it done in DOM so far, the more important is collusion. and calculating 2nd point

Comment: probably canvas, it is better performance I think and s probably faster for collision detection (with elements, it's more "bulky" and you have to run `getBoundingClientRect()` and such. With your canvas, you could simply hold coords in an array or object, making things much, much faster)

Comment: Nah i dont need getBoundingClientRec as i use coords as well with y,X  and radius , also if i use the way i am doing collision now on canvas it wont change anything as i simply run a script to check for collision, it has nothing to do with canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone.

I've found the solution to what i were looking for.

about the collision the way i was doing it was entirely wrong i will list the correct way farther down.

about the distance - the solution i came up with is checking the distance from player's current position to object if player's step is bigger then distance, deduct step from distance and walk that distance.

as for canvas vs dom - seems both has their crons and pros.

Now for the collision
the correct way of doing it is to create a pixel map array. so if your canvas or container node is width:800 by height:500 you'll have a 2d array that represent those pixes

and then when i check for position i simply check if player's current position + steps toward future position has an object.

so like :

```
if(array[300][500]){
    return false;
}
```

That's what i found out.

If anyone have a better solution then that let me know.